# Hide or show fields when button is clicked using infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

In Infopath form i have two buttons, when one button is clicked only some fields are to be shown others should be invisible, when another button is clicked other fields only be visible. 
 I get it only some conditional values are set using formatting condition.

How come i get it when buttons are clicked

Answer (score 2):

Place all the controls in a section and apply rules on the button click. You can show and hide the default fields and based on button click show and hide the relevant section.

[Hide and show sections](http://isharepoint2010.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/step-for-creating-form-add-new-field.html)

[Hide sections in InfoPath forms](http://www.edutechnow.com/?p=1376)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but it was one of the only search results, so I'm going to put in how to do it.

Make a picture button, text box and section.

Section Rules: 
text box doesn't equal 2, formatting, hide this control

Picture Button Rules:

1. text box is blank OR text box = 3, Action, Set field's value: text
   box = 2
2. text box = 2, Action, Set field's value: text box = 3

The text box does not need to be present on the form.

What this does is it creates a loop and allows for multiple clicking. So when you click on the button the text box says 2 and section will show. When you click again the text box will say 3 and the section will hide.

After applying rule 1., you need to check the box "Don't run remaining rules...". If you don't check this box, it will not loop.

Comment: It worked for me.Thank you so much for posting this Brittany

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution in case you'll want to hide or show sections, which mimics an ajax call without a page refresh similar to the ones you'll find in a React or Angular SPAs, sort of a navbar within infopath.

1. Create 3 buttons **(button1, button2, button3)**
2. Create 3 Sections containing any unique content you want , so you can see results
3. Create 3 **textfields** with numneric values and give them default values such as:

   ```
       Part1 = default value of 1 , let's call it part1State = 1
       Part2 = default value of 0 , let's call it part2State = 0
       Part3 = default value of 0 , let's call it part3State = 0
   ```
4. Section Rules:

   ```
    Section 1:
       Type: Formatting, Condition: part1State=0, HIDE THIS CONTROL
    Section 2:
       Type: Formatting, Condition: part2State=0, HIDE THIS CONTROL
    Section 3:
       Type: Formatting, Condition: part3State=0, HIDE THIS CONTROL
   ```
5. Button Rules ( no condition for any of them)

   ```
   Button 1:
        Type: Action, Set a fields value part1State=1
        Type: Action, Set a fields value part2State=0
        Type: Action, Set a fields value part3State=0
   Button 2:
        Type: Action, Set a fields value part1State=0
        Type: Action, Set a fields value part2State=1
        Type: Action, Set a fields value part3State=0
   Button 3:
        Type: Action, Set a fields value part1State=0
        Type: Action, Set a fields value part2State=0
        Type: Action, Set a fields value part3State=1
   ```